# Do mobile browsers caches take into account POST parameters?

Tags: php, web-services, caching

I started adding caching headers to my PHP web service for my ios and android apps. Each time these apps make a request to the server, they have specific POST parameters that affect the output of the visited url.

I wonder if there is a cache hit when the same page is visited but with different post parameters?

EDIT to answer questions:

A typical use case of my web service is the page getGameInfo.php:

```
// Set HTTP Cache
$seconds_to_cache = 400;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: {$ts}");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age={$seconds_to_cache}");

// Read POST parameter
$gameId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gameId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Get the info for the game
// (Here I query the database and echo the data of this game)
```

So my question is: when this page is visited a second time but with a different gameId, will there be a cache hit?

Comment: What caching headers? And on what requests?

Comment: why does **get**GameInfo.php require a **POST** request??

Comment: Odd (poor) design aside, this question appears to be about client side caching, so to answer that we would need to see the client side code - if the apps are using standard web browsers to communicate, then the answer is probably no - a sanely coded webbrowser will not cache POST requests.

Comment: @Steve Ok I realize I should definitely not use post requests for this but a get request.  Thank you for your answer. While we are at it, can you explain why it is a poor design as well?

Comment: I was just referring to using POST requests for an idempotent operation, when you should be using GET. There are a number of reasons why that is poor design, this cache issue being one of them. I wasnt suggesting there is anything else wrong